# Changing Contol Parent Removes Content

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, parent, tabcontrol

In my application, I have a DataGridView that moves from one Tab Control to another Tab Control.

I am doing this by changing its parent. This works with no problems on the first move from the origional Tab Control to the new one, but when changing the parent back to the origional, the DataGridView shows up (all the Columns are visible) but there is no data in the view.

I have tried to reload the data into the DataGridView, and refresh/Invalidate the control to make it redraw, but it still shows up empty. However, when the control goes back to the secondary parent, the data is back.

I am also using this exact code for another DataGridView and it works without any problems at all.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance.

From Origional to Secondary

```
gvwRFIs.Parent = tabProcessingRFI; //Working
gvwConsentInfoMemos.Parent = tabProcessingMemos; //Working
```

From Secondary to Origional

```
gvwRFIs.Parent = tabConsentInfoRFI; //Empty Data
gvwConsentInfoMemos.Parent = tabConsentInfoMemos; //Working
```

RFI DataGridView Designer Code

```
        // 
        // gvwRFIs
        // 
        this.gvwRFIs.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.gvwRFIs.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.gvwRFIs.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        this.gvwRFIs.AutoSizeRowsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCellsExceptHeaders;
        this.gvwRFIs.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.gvwRFIs.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.gvwRFIs.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.gvwID,
        this.gvwType,
        this.gvwSeq,
        this.gvwCreated,
        this.gvwProcessor,
        this.gvwLetter,
        this.gvwResponded,
        this.gvwS,
        this.gvwDetails});
        this.gvwRFIs.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.gvwRFIs.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this.gvwRFIs.MultiSelect = false;
        this.gvwRFIs.Name = "gvwRFIs";
        this.gvwRFIs.ReadOnly = true;
        this.gvwRFIs.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        this.gvwRFIs.RowHeadersWidth = 4;
        this.gvwRFIs.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        this.gvwRFIs.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1078, 422);
        this.gvwRFIs.TabIndex = 4;
        this.gvwRFIs.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.gvwRFIs_DoubleClick);
```

Consent Tab Control Designer Code

```
        // 
        // tabConsentInfoRFI
        // 
        this.tabConsentInfoRFI.Controls.Add(this.gvwRFIs);
        this.tabConsentInfoRFI.Controls.Add(this.lvwConsentInfoRFI);
        this.tabConsentInfoRFI.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 32);
        this.tabConsentInfoRFI.Name = "tabConsentInfoRFI";
        this.tabConsentInfoRFI.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabConsentInfoRFI.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1084, 428);
        this.tabConsentInfoRFI.TabIndex = 4;
        this.tabConsentInfoRFI.Text = "RFI\'s";
        this.tabConsentInfoRFI.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

Processing Tab Control Designer Code

```
        // 
        // tabProcessingRFI
        // 
        this.tabProcessingRFI.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 36);
        this.tabProcessingRFI.Name = "tabProcessingRFI";
        this.tabProcessingRFI.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabProcessingRFI.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(868, 465);
        this.tabProcessingRFI.TabIndex = 1;
        this.tabProcessingRFI.Text = "RFI";
        this.tabProcessingRFI.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

Comment: If the code works on the other grid, then the problem isn't going to be with the posted code.  Try looking at any event handlers that could be causing the issue.

Comment: The only event that this or the other DataGridView handles is the doubleclick event. I will post the Designer code for both the DataGridViews above. All the double click events do is open another Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue,
The ListView that is in the consent designer code, is an old control that looks identical, but is no longer used. So when the control is parented back to the Origional tab, it is in the background of this control.
Once the control was removed (thought it already was) the code worked perfectly.

Thank you to LarsTech for getting me in the right direction. And akhisp for there answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the object from the Tab.Controls list of the tab that it's no longer in. So do something like:

```
tabProcessingRFI.Controls.Remove(gvwRFIs);
gvwRFIs.Parent = tabConsentInfoRFI
```